# Why is this date range query so slow?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with 5 million rows, I am running:

```
select
    *
from
    tbl
where
    datetime_created
between
   '2014-10-01 00:00:00' and
   '2014-10-31 23:59:59'
```

It took 54 seconds to return 428k results

The columns on the tbl:

```
id (int pk auto inc)
actor (varchar)
action (enum)
target (varchar)
is_successful (tinyint)
datetime_created (datetime)
```

The index:

```
datetime_created (datetime_created, action, target, is_successful)
```

Any ideas on how I can improve this?

edit:

EXPLAIN results:

```
select_type: simple
type: range
possible keys
datetime_created
key: datetime_created
key_len: 8
ref: null
rows: 359569
extra: using index condition
```

Comment: prefix explain before the query and see what it is doing

Comment: explain: select_type: simple, type: range, possible keys: datetime_created, key: datetime_created, key_len: 8, ref: null, rows: 359569, extra: using index condition

Comment: explain shows that it is using the index, but the performance is still really bad

Comment: Are you running this query over a WAN without compression perhaps? Also note depending on the record length this could be quite a few megabytes.

Comment: My guess is your data doesn't fit in memory, so MySQL is doing a lot of random disk access to fetch the result. One solution would be using covering index, i.e. `select datetime_created, action, target, is_successful, id` only(or the subset of those columns), but that is not always possible, depending on what columns you really need.

Comment: Do you need all columns to be selected actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

428k is a lot of rows to work with in one shot . Even though you have an index on date, the engine still has to scan through the table between the high and low values. I would suggest multiple queries reading the data in smaller chunks and narrowing result set if possible.

E.g. Try adding action enum filter together with the date range should yield much faster results. Say there are 5 enum types then you run 5 queries for each action enum. The more indexed criteria you add the better the query will perform .

Also consider if this is going to be used in an app, that is a massive recordset to deal with. Do you really need to work with 428k results at a time?

Comment: It's essentially a database table that I'm using as a 'log' -- I need to do some counting based on different action types, etc.

Comment: So you need to do aggregation. If you add in your group by statement on action then it will better utilize the index.

Answer (score 0):

The table is not very big.
I just solved this problem with the following changes. Other methods don't work.

1. I upgraded mysql version from 5.7 to 8
2. I fixed the mysql used memory to half of the server's memory. (If the server is 2gb, you should allocate 1gb for mysql)